# Create npm package of my react native app

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-package

- Right now I am working on npm package for my react native app,My app contain lots of things, like have a native modules, lots of dependencies,I am using [this](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-builder-bob/blob/main/README.md) to create npm package for my app.
- Question 1 - Above package (Mentioned as this) is good for create npm package for my react native app?
- Question 2 - As I mentioned that my react native app contain native modules too how can I manage into npm package?

Many thanks in advance